# how to reduce the width of a column chart in MS excel

Tags: excel, charts

I want to reduce the width of the bar on value 1.9 in the attached Column chart image.
I tried to change the gap width but it doesn't take values more than 500.

I have uploaded the Excel file to this [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/XsrZJ4m0ce/Book2.html)

[image]

Comment: Is the purpose of reducing the width of the column to produce a vertical line?

Comment: @Clif No, I just want to reduce the width but don't want it to be converted into line, so that I could have the control on the width.